# Elasticsearch simple query string with three ors ( | ) returns no value

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been working with simple query string to query information inside of elastic but I ran into a problem.

When I create a query like:

```
"simple_query_string":{
  "query":"\"this is a phrase\" | KEYWORD_1 | KEYWORD_2",
    "fields":[
      "field_1",
      "field_2",
      "field_3",
    ],
  }
```

It return 0 results, meanwhile if the query is structured with parenthesis:

```
"simple_query_string":{
  "query":"(\"this is a phrase\" | KEYWORD_1) | KEYWORD_2",
    "fields":[
      "field_1",
      "field_2",
      "field_3",
    ],
  }
```

It works smoothly.

I was wondering if I'm missing something in elastic's documentation.

Comment: Its implied in the parent Query string query documentation, but I agree with you its not well explained. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators

Comment: That's true @IanGabes, exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!

Comment: @davidsrn has been a long time that you have not accepted and upvoted my answer, it would be great if u can accept and upvote the answer if your issue is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [IanGabes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4858238/iangabes) said in a comment:

According to [elasticsearch's documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators):

`foo bar +baz -qux`

The familiar boolean operators AND, OR and NOT (also written &&, || and !) are also supported but beware that they do not honor the usual precedence rules, so parentheses should be used whenever multiple operators are used together. For instance the previous query could be rewritten as:

`((foo AND baz) OR (bar AND baz) OR baz) AND NOT qux`

Or in simple query lenguaje:

`((foo + baz) | (bar + baz) | baz) + -qux`

Regarding my example:

`"this is a phrase" | KEYWORD_1 | KEYWORD_2`

Could be extended to

`("this is a phrase" | KEYWORD_1) | ("this is a phrase" | KEYWORD_2) | (KEYWORD_1 | KEYWORD_2)`

But is, in a simpler way:

`("this is a phrase" | KEYWORD_1) | KEYWORD_2`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result. To know more about Simple Query string parameters refer to this official documentation on [simple query string syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html#simple-query-string-syntax)

**Index Data**

```
{
    "name":"multi",
    "title":"Science",
    "shape":"triangle"
}
{
    "name":"multi grain bread",
    "title":"Maths",
    "shape":"square"
}
{
    "name":"multi",
    "title":"Science",
    "shape":"square"
}
```

**Search Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "\"multi grain bread\" | Maths | square",
      "fields": [
        "title",
        "name",
        "shape"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.6891878,
        "_source": {
          "name": "multi grain bread",
          "title": "Maths",
          "shape": "square"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.47000363,
        "_source": {
          "name": "multi",
          "title": "Science",
          "shape": "square"
        }
      }
    ]
```